# HashMap with Flux in Reactive Programming

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-webflux

I have to convert the following code into the non-blocking(asynchronous) process.

### EmpController class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/emp")
public class EmpController {

 private EmployeeRepository empRepo;

@Autowired
public EmpController(EmployeeRepository empRepo)
{
    this.empRepo=empRepo;
}

   @PostMapping("/save/all")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void saveEmpAll(@RequestBody List<Employee> emps)
    {
        empRepo.saveEmpAll(emps);
    }
}
```

### EmployeeRepository class

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeRepository implements EmployeeDAO {

 @Override
    public void saveEmpAll(List<Employee> emps) {

        Map<Long,Employee> employees=new HashMap<>();

        emps.forEach(emp->{
            emp.setDate(new Date());
            employees.put(emp.getId(),emp);
        });
        hashOperations.putAll("EMP",employees);
    }

}
```

Use Reactive Programming with Spring Webflux

controller

```
@PostMapping("/save/all")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void saveEmpAll(@RequestBody Flux<Employee> emps)
    {
        emps.collectMap(e->{
           e.setDate(new Date());
           // todo.............( can I do like this? is it the right way?)
        });
    }
```

ropository

```
  @Override
    public void saveEmpAll(Map<Long,Employee> employees) {
        hashOperations.putAll("EMP",employees);
    }
```

is there any other way to create HashMap and put values into it in an asynchronous way with Flux?

Comment: `Map<Long, Employee> employees = employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(employee -> employee.getId(), employee -> employee));` You can try like this as well.